How to fix ripped out drywall towel/robe hook?
We have a hook used for towels and robes in the bathroom. It was accidentally ripped down when someone unintentionally pulled on a towel with too much force.
I have no idea how to go about this. I am not a handy person and am quite worried.

Easiest good-looking fix is to get a panel with many robe hooks, such as some of those in Amazon query.
Remove other robe hooks, and cover the damaged area with the panel, screwing it into studs to support the weight. Use a stud finder, if need be.
The result will look better than the original separate hooks, will be far sturdier, and will protect the wall somewhat from contact with clothing and hands.

There are a bunch of ways to fix it. But the best permanent fix is to attach any hook and/or bar to wood, either directly or indirectly. Which basically gives you two options, depending on the amount of finish work you want to do, what the existing finish is (painted walls can be made "good as new", wallpaper is more of a problem) and other factors.
Wood Inside

Cut open more of the wall, enough to expose studs on both sides. Studs will typically be 16" apart. Cut the space into a nice clean rectangle for easy patching.
Cut wood to fit the open space, including where you want to install the hooks and/or bar supports. The wood can be plywood or a piece of 2x4 or whatever works for you, as long as it is sturdy. It doesn't have to look nice.
Screw the wood into the studs.
Cut drywall to match the open space and screw it to the wood.
Patch and paint. Note that this can be quite involved depending on the finish quality desired.
Install the new hooks and/or bar supports into the wood.

Wood Outside

Patch the hole in the drywall, just enough to be reasonably smooth. But doesn't need to look perfect or be painted, etc.
Cut a nice piece of wood, (a) large enough to cover the newly patched location, (b) long enough to reach two studs and (c) large enough to support any hooks and/or bar supports you want to install.
Before installing the wood, stain it or paint it to match your bathroom decor. Stain works well if you have other stained wood in the bathroom and can make it match. Otherwise, paint in the same color as the bathroom trim works well.
Screw the wood into two studs.
Screw the hooks and/or bar supports into the wood.

Wood inside provides a hidden support method but may require a lot more drywall finish work. Wood outside is obvious, but done well can look like very nice.
